# Is it possible to send get request as logged user in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I need to get the page source of Yii2 web page, which requires authorization.

For example, there are some posts like mysite.pro/post/123, these pages are available only for logged users. I created a view that can show posts in an editor, so I want to get the code of the post and try to get it with:

```
file_get_contents('http://mysite.pro/post/123',false),
```

However, the server returns me a 403 code.

Is there a way to get the page as a current Yii2 user?

Comment: show the  related  controller action code  .. with behaviors access rules  too

Comment: Sorry, but no( 
I mean, what is authority? Set of http request params and ip. There should be a way to do this!
Thanks for your answer, I have marked it as a usefull, but it is not a solution

Comment: Well, you have said what's wrong with my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is forbidden due to security. But it's possible to display specific content from different file. This is why we have `renderPartial` thing. A quick example:

**view_file.php**:

```
<?php
// ...
echo Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('special_content');
```

**special_content.php**:

```
<?php

if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    echo "I'm visible only to registered users. ";
} else {
    echo "I'm visible only to guests. ";
}

echo "I'm visible to both types. ";
```

If user is logged in, then he will see: `I'm visible only to registered users. And I'm visible to both types.` Otherwise: `I'm visible only to guests. And I'm visible to both types.`

Such thing is good since it gives flexibility how you want to display content from another file.

Quick note: you shouldn't be using like `$this->title` in your **special_content.php** because it will overwrite your **view_file.php**.